# java ormlite ForeignCollectionField with generic abstract class occur java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, generics, ormlite

When OrmliteSqliteOpenHelper gets daos, it occurs `java.sql.SQLException: Field class for 'detailCollection' must be a parameterized Collection whose generic argument is an entity class not: T`

How can I solve this problem? Here is part of classes.

```
public abstract class AbstractOrder<T> {

    @ForeignCollectionField()
    private Collection<T> detailCollection;

}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = Constants.TABLE_TABLEORDER)
public class TableOrderModel extends AbstractOrder<TableOrderDetailModel> {

    ...

}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = Constants.TABLE_CUSTOMER)
public class CustomerModel extends AbstractModel {

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private TableOrderModel tableOrder;
}
```